# Laravel 5: Having trouble updating related model values by using save/push methods, they just don't work

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to update some values of a related model but after assigning the new values and using `save()` or `push()` the values are not updated in database. More than that, execution just stops at those methods and all I can see is a blank page. No errors, no nothing, it just doesn't even reach the return statement. If I use the try-catch, it just skips the `save()` or `push()`.

Here is the **Product** model (just without the fields and methods that are not related to what I'm currently trying to do):

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = "products";

    public $timestamps = false;

    public $fillable = [
        ...
    ];

    public function userProduct()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("\\App\\Models\\UserProduct", "id", "product_id");
    }
}
```

The **UserProduct** model with fields which I'm trying to update:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserProduct extends Model
{

    protected $primaryKey = null;
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $table = "user_product";

    public $fillable = [
        ...
        "is_featured",
        "is_hidden_from_latest"
        ...
    ];

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("\\App\\Models\\Product", "product_id", "id");
    }

    public function pendingProduct()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("\\App\\Models\\PendingProduct", "target_product_id", "target_product");
    }

}
```

Code from the controller:

```
$replaced_product_sku = Input::get("replaced_sku");
$new_product_sku = Input::get("new_sku");

$products = Product::with([
    "userProduct" => function($q) {
        $q->orderBy("updated_at", "asc");
    }
])->where("product_status", "live")->get();

if (!$found_replaced = $products->where("item_sku", $replaced_product_sku)->first()) {
    return redirect("admin/content")
        ->with("danger", "Replaced product was not found.");
}

if (!$found_new = $products->where("item_sku", $new_product_sku)->first()) {
    return redirect("admin/content")
        ->with("danger", "The new featured product was not found.");
}

$found_replaced->userProduct->is_featured = 0;
$found_replaced->userProduct->is_hidden_from_latest = 1;
$found_new->userProduct->is_featured = 1;
$found_new->userProduct->is_hidden_from_latest = 0;

$found_replaced->userProduct->save();
$found_new->userProduct->save();

return redirect("admin/content")
    ->with("...", "...");
```

Tried using `push()` method instead of `save()` but the only thing that happens is that execution stops at `$found_replaced->userProduct->save();` and a blank page is displayed. Also tried something like this:

```
$found_replaced->update([
    "userProduct.is_featured" => 0,
    "userProduct.is_hidden_from_latest" => 1
]);

$found_new->update([
    "userProduct.is_featured" => 1,
    "userProduct.is_hidden_from_latest" => 0
]);
```

but still without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was using this approach:

```
$found_replaced->update([
    "userProduct.is_featured" => 0,
    "userProduct.is_hidden_from_latest" => 1
]);

$found_new->update([
    "userProduct.is_featured" => 1,
    "userProduct.is_hidden_from_latest" => 0
]);
```

that I've posted in the question, but the mistake was that I was using it wrong, so I've edited it into this and it worked fine:

```
$found_replaced->userProduct()->update([
    "is_featured" => 0,
    "is_hidden_from_latest" => 1
]);

$found_new->userProduct()->update([
    "is_featured" => 1,
    "is_hidden_from_latest" => 0
]);
```

Seems that `save()` just doesn't work as expected on relation attributes.

Thank you for your help anyway! ;)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to fix the relations:

In **Product** model:

```
public function userProduct()
{
    return $this->hasOne("\\App\\Models\\UserProduct", "product_id", "id");
}
```

In **UserProduct** model:

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo("\\App\\Models\\Product", "product_id", "id");
}
```

Comment: The relations are okay, everything works fine with relations that I currently have. If to replace `belongsTo` with `hasOne` in `Product` model it throws me the following exception: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_product.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `user_product` where `user_product`.`id` in () order by `updated_at` asc)`

Comment: can you show your 'products' and 'user_products' tables?

Comment: Yes, it fixed the previous situation when there was an exception thrown, but it still didn't solve the initial issue. The execution just stops at first usage of `save()` or `push()` methods. Really strange behavior.

Comment: Debugging step by step) ... edit your question and we will move on